# How can I include a list inside a string

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

I want to include a list variable inside a string. Like this:

```
aStr = """
blah blah blah 
blah = ["one","two","three"]
blah blah
"""
```

I tried these:

```
l = ["one","two","three"]
aStr = """
blah blah blah 
blah = %s
blah blah
"""%str(l)
```

OR

```
l = ["one","two","three"]
aStr = """
blah blah blah 
blah = """+str(l)+"""
blah blah
"""
```

They didn't work unfortunately

Comment: What are you attempting to accomplish by doing this?  Do you just want to get the text from your list concatenated into your string?  Or are you trying to store the list inside of your string in a way that you can still access the indices of the list within the string?

Comment: At the end I just want a string which includes the list I want. I am not gonna use it as a list anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your snippets work almost the way you mention. The only difference is that the line that includes your list has spaces after each comma. The attached code gives exactly the output you wanted.

```
l = ["one","two","three"]
aStr = """
blah blah blah 
blah = %s
blah blah
"""% ('["'+'","'.join(l)+'"]')
```

So what does that do?

The most interesting part here is this one `'","'.join(l)`. The `.join()` method takes the string that is passed before the dot and joins every element of the list separated by that string.

Other ways of doing this:

```
l = [1,2,3]
"a "+str(l)+" b"
"a {} b".format(l)
"a {name} b".format(name=l)
f"a {l} b"
```

Comment: What if the string includes % character in it?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a string that includes the list, you could do:

```
s1 = "blah blah blah"
l = [1,2,3]
s2 = "blah blah blah"
s3 = s1 + str(l) + s2
```

Answer (score -1):

How about this using f string.

```
strQ =f"""
blah blah blah 
blah = {l}
blah blah"""
```

This will give :

```
"\nblah blah blah \nblah = ['one', 'two', 'three']\nblah blah\n"
```

This will work in python 3.6 and beyond however not in below 3.6.